# How to work with HEAT.exe for dll registry

Tags: dll, wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

and i need to register a dll . Right now am registering the dll as below

```
<CustomAction Id='comReg' Directory='INSTALLLOCATION'  Impersonate='no' Execute='deferred'  
                ExeCommand='"[NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENTINSTALLROOTDIR]regasm.exe" "[INSTALLLOCATION]myProduct.dll"  /codebase' Return='check' />
```

but all are suggesting to use HEAT.exe in internet wherever and whenever i surf . I even have gone through [this link.](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) But there they have only the syntax etc. I really dont know how to work with it just by knowing those syntax.

**I need some step by step procedure or some good blog which elaborately tell how how to harvest a dll and how to impllement it in to wix code and how the registry will be done** , so that i can register my dll based on conditions also.Even i tried this [link](http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.in/2013/06/using-wix-heat-to-harvest-files-for-wix.html) alse

Regards

Comment: Are you building with Visual Studio and/or MSBuild, or creating your own command for heat?

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes am building with visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Registering a COM component is done through standard Windows Installer actions and tables. Numerous table entries are required so WiX provides heat.exe to harvest COM files. It works by inspecting a file for type libraries and, if the DllRegisterServer entry point is present, running it in a Registry sandbox where changes are intercepted and captured. (In the era of Windows Installer [1999-present], DllRegisterServer is effectively deprecated for any other purpose.)

As you may know, a Feature is the smallest user-selectable unit of installation. A Component is a member of one or Features in one or more Products. Heat creates a component for each file it harvests and a ComponenentGroup for each harvest run. So, you have to pick a ComponentGroup Id and reference it in one or more Features. You also have to pick a Directory Id for the destination of the ComponentGroup.

Now, it is simply a matter of editing your project file to harvest the file. To edit a project file you could use a text editor but Visual Studio is all set up for it. See [How to: Edit Project Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171487(v=vs.90).aspx).

1. Add a HarvestFile element to a new or existing ItemGroup, entering the desired ComponentGroup Id and Directory Id

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
       <HarvestFile Include="comserver.dll">
           <ComponentGroupName>COM</ComponentGroupName>
           <DirectoryRefId>ServerDir</DirectoryRefId>
       </HarvestFile>
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
2. In your Product.wxs or elsewhere, add a ComponentGroupRef to one or more Features.